# sort an array using pointers and without any index variables

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

i am trying to sort an array, using pointers and also without using index variables

```
void sort(int *a,int n)
{
  int *temp;
  *temp=0;
  int *b=a;
  for(;a<a+n-1;a+=1)
    {
      for(b=a+1;b<b+n;b+=1)
        {
          if(*a>*b)
          {
            *temp=*a;
            *a=*b;
            *b=*temp;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

the equivalent version of the above program without using pointers is

```
void sort(int a[],int n)
{
  int i,j,temp;
  for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
      for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
          if(a[i]>a[j])
          {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

i am doing an exercise question, and i just started learning the pointers by myself. i believe i am doing it right as i am trying to avoid the usage of index variables too. i am receiving an error `segmentation fault : 11` . what am i missing here?
is the program wrong in someway? or the idea itself is wrong? feedback appreciated.

Comment: We could go crazy and use variable names more than one character long. You know, if we wanted.

Comment: Note: both versions use pointers only. You never use an array for any access.

Comment: @Olaf yes that's true. whenever you pass an array to a function, it actually passes a pointer to the first element of the array. is that right ?

Comment: Rolled back. You must not change the question once you got an answer. Just add clarifications or append text to the question with a note.

Comment: @buggenerator: Not just that. `int a[10]; a[1];`: here `a[1]` already uses a pointer. (I will not further elborate, just do some research on your own)

Comment: @Olaf alright. thanks. I'm new to stackoverflow, I'll take a note of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a<a+n-1` - that's always true if `n` > 1.

BTW, the argument `int a[]` decays to a pointer.

Comment: yes that's true. but still not getting what you were implying ?

Comment: A loop whose loop condition is always true, is an infinite loop - that is, you walk right off the end of the array and keep going, sorting all the memory you can reach until the program crashes. If you tried this on an old (pre-protected memory) OS, you'd probably have to power-cycle the machine to stop it.

Answer (score 3):

These two lines are wrong:

```
int *temp;
*temp=0;
```

In the first line, you declare a pointer variable. This variable points *somewhere*, but as long as you don’t assign any value to this variable, you cannot know where it points.

Then, in the second line, you say: Wherever `temp` points to, write a zero into that memory cell. So the program writes to a random unknown address.

In your case, `temp` should not be a pointer at all, since you later need it to store an `int`.

As a general rule, you should not change the parameters to a function, in this case `a`. Rather, create one more local variable. This will prevent another bug in your code where you compare `b<b+n`. That expression can be transformed to `0<n` for all situations except overflow. The expression should rather be `p<a+n`, where `p` is your new local variable.

Comment: yes @Roland Illig . it's a rookie mistake, i understood what i've done wrong in that

Answer (score 2):

```
*temp=0;
```

is not allowed: You have not allocated memory for `temp`

Either use :

```
int temp;
```

or do

```
 int *temp;
   temp=malloc(1*sizeof(*temp)); // The dirty way.
```

Comment: alright i have made a change. created a variable and assigned the pointer to that variable to the temp. still receiving same error

Comment: Yep, just use `int temp = 0;` - it's not an index variable, so you don't need to change it somehow to a pointer for your exercise

Comment: Damn, that's a more easy way. but i am still receiving an error?

Comment: @sjsam i don't know what does that malloc do. i just started learning pointers and that's an exercise question

Comment: @buggenerator : just allocating 4 bytes of memory for storing and integer value.  But don't use it here. It makes the code dirty

Answer (score 2):

Omnibus edition (UB = Undefined Behaviour = bugs and errors):

```
void sort(int *a,int n)
{
  int *temp;
  *temp=0;  // UB: assignment to uninitialized pointer
  int *b=a;
  for(;a<a+n-1;a+=1) // UB: a<a+n-1 is always true so this is infinite
    {
```

first we'll replace `int *temp` with `int temp=0` as per sjsam's answer.

```
void sort(int *a,int n)
{
  int temp=0;  // not an index variable, doesn't have to change to pointer
```

That leaves the infinite loop: you need to remember where the array ends even as you iterate through it:

```
  int *begin = a;
  int *end = a + n; // one-past-the-end for a half-open interval
  for (int *i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
```

Note that you'll need an equivalent change for the nested loop, and `*temp` should just be `temp` in the element swap.

Comment: alright i got it now, let me know what i interpreted is right,

in the above program as i am increasing the value of `a` and also i am checking whether `a<a+n-1`. which leads to an infinite loop. isn't it?

Comment: Yes - the first time round, `a + n` is the same as my `end`. But, the second time round the loop, `end` stayed put (at the end of the array), while `a + n` has moved since we increased `a`. The value isn't taken once at the start unless you do that manually - the whole expression `(a < a + n)` gets evaluated each time.